# Rails validation to make something not editable if live

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my head around rails validation. So far i have this

```
  def live
    person.live
  end
```

However i have no idea what to do after this, The users have a button to click to make there person live. Which changes a value in the DB from false to true.

they then have a link to be able to edit the user which is here

```
/people/{{person.id}}/edit
```

How do i make it so the users cannot access the link (via typing it into the browser) after the event is live?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"How do i make it so the users cannot access the link (via typing it into the browser) after the event is live?"*

You can use [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) filter to check if `live` field is true. Something like:

Controller:

```
before_action :check_if_live_true

private

def check_if_live_true
    if live_field.true?
        redirect_to some_path
    end
end
```

Which will redirect if the `live` field is true, then someone enters the matching URL.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using some kind of authorization gem. Personally i use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

There you can specifiy what a user can access and not and where it should redirect to etc.

In Ability.rb specify this

```
can :update, Person, :live => false
```

In Controllers use this

```
authorize! :edit, @person
```

In views you can then use something like this

```
<% if can? :update, @person%>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_person_path(@person) %>
<% end %>
```